# Laravel - For in blade with HTML from lang?

Tags: php, html, laravel, for-loop, backend

I'm new to Laravel and I'm facing a (I suppose) common problem, but couldn't find this specific scenario in the documentation:

I'm building a two language website and I'm filling HTML from a file in my langs folder.
So I want to know how to make a proper `for loop` inside this code:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <h2 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">Bem-vindo ao <span>SysSite!</span></h2>
        <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">{!! __('pages/index.carrossel1') !!}</p>
        <a href="" class="btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Read sd</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Slide 2 -->
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-container">
        <h2 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">Conecte-se e divulgue suas ideias!</h2>
        <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Crie postagens, comente, intereja e o mais importante: <br />evolua seu conhecimento sobre suas tecnologias favoritas!</p>
        <a href="" class="btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Slide 3 -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <h2 class="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">Sequi ea ut et est quaerat</h2>
            <p class="animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Ut velit est quam dolor ad a aliquid qui aliquid. Sequi ea ut et est quaerat sequi nihil ut aliquam. Occaecati alias dolorem mollitia ut. Similique ea voluptatem. Esse doloremque accusamus repellendus deleniti vel. Minus et tempore modi architecto.</p>
            <a href="" class="btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My `index.php` file, in the langs folder:

```
<?php
return [
'carrossel1' => 'Mantenha-se por dentro de tudo que rola no mundo da tecnologia! <br />Atualizações diárias para te manter antenado.'
];
```

So, my question is: for the time I don't have the text for every div, but when I do, how can I make it dynamically filled, with a for loop and my array in `index.text`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lang('index.'.$carrossel)  or 
    {!! __('index.'.$carrossel) !!}

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Localization by laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization) as its standard and easy to use.

as you can create a new folder within the lang file so you can get as following

[image: This is how u need to place the file]

in the lang.php

```php
<?php
    return [ 
        'carrossel1'=> 'Mantenha-se por dentro de tudo que rola no mundo da tecnologia! <br />Atualizações diárias para te manter antenado.'
    ]
?>
```

and you can easily access it as

```php
{!! __('lang.carrossel1') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can two ways .Given an simple example below

```
$carousel=[
    [
    'key'=>'carrossel1'
    ]
    [
    'key'=>'carrossel2'
    ],
    [
    'key'=>'carrossel3'
    ]
    ];
    
    @foreach($carousel as $key=>$value)
    
    @lang('index.'.$value['key']) or {!! __('index.'.$value['key']) !!} 
    
    @endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($carousel as $key=>$value)


{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::get('index')[$value['key']]}}

@endforeach
```